# Not all JSON entries are returned in ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, missing-data

Im learning angularjs. So far I have managed to get a table to populate using a standard ng-repeat directive within a single controller. I am using a JSON file stored on github. Result.

However, I have 1 problem.  The JSON file has 15 objects(?) and each object has 14 attributes.

The json is valid according to JSONlint. A snippet of the json is below

```
[
    {
        "Room_ID": "1",
        "OldRoom": "room1oldname",
        "NewRoom": "room1newname",
        "floor": "First Floor",
        "facilities": "Y",
        "NoSeats": "4",
        "PC": "1",
        "flipchart": "N",
        "conferencePhone": "N",
        "phone": "Y",
        "whiteboard": "N",
        "projector": "N",
        "waterFountain": "N",
        "NoOfProjectorScreens": "0"
    },
    {
        "Room_ID": "2",
        "OldRoom": "Room2Oldname",
        "NewRoom": "Room2Newname",
        "floor": "First Floor",
        "facilities": "N",
        "NoSeats": "4",
        "PC": "0",
        "flipchart": "N",
        "conferencePhone": "N",
        "phone": "N",
        "whiteboard": "N",
        "projector": "N",
        "waterFountain": "N",
        "NoOfProjectorScreens": "0"
    }
]
```

Originally it looked like all items with names containing spaces weren't being returned. For example "water fountain" was not returned, but "whiteboard" was.  I changed all the entries to remove spaces and rechecked the validity of the json but no dice.

Ive tried returning data from various sample apis and haven't had any trouble other than this particular json source.

I also tried the $index by x but not sure I did this correctly or if its what i needed since each entry in JSON has its own unique ID.

I presume it must be something to do with the JSON itself otherwise no other results would be returned from this or any other source file.

I presently get 15 rows of data (1 per room), but some of the columns are blank.

I have only been doing this a week, apologies if I have some of the semantics incorrect.

Thank you for your time.

Long time lurker, new time asker

EDIT: Hi, apologies for the delay. I can't add a plunker as I don't know how to use it.  But I am only using two files so I will post the code below.

Index.html and controller.js

Controller.js code

```
angular
.module("roomviewer", [])

.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {


var onUserComplete = function(response){
    $scope.user = response.data;
};

var onError = function(reason){
    $scope.error = "oh no";
};


    $http.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cnrowland/78f5d20bd175028e1051/raw/42246133908e126f2c53303d97a10fff9d43ff07/roomMaster.json")
.then(onUserComplete, onError);

});
```

Index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="roomviewer">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Room Viewer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/controller.js"></script>



</head>
<body data-ng-controller = "MainController">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
         data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-toggle">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 ￼</button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Room Viewer</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-toggle">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">See All Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="/add">Filter Rooms</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>
</nav>

<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Room ID</th>
          <th>New Room</th>
          <th>Old Room</th>
          <th>Location</th>
          <th>Facilities</th>
          <th>No of PCs</th>
          <th>Flipchart</th>
          <th>Conference Phone</th>
          <th>Telephone</th>
          <th>Whiteboard</th>
          <th>Water Fountain</th>
          <th>Projector</th>
          <th>No. of Projector Screens</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in user" track by $user.Room_ID>
          <th>{{user.Room_ID}}</th>
          <th>{{user.NewRoom}}</th>
          <th>{{user.OldRoom}}</th>
          <th>{{user.floor}}</th>
          <th>{{user.facilities}}</th>
          <th>{{user.PC}}</th>
          <th>{{user.flipchart}}</th>
          <th>{{user.conferencePhone}}</th>
          <th>{{user.phone}}</th>
          <th>{{user.whiteboard}}</th>
          <th>{{user.waterFountain}}</th>
          <th>{{user.projector}}</th>
          <th>{{user.NoOfProjectorScreens}}</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>


</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your angularJS code?

Comment: Missing { at the beginning od line 16

Comment: create a demo on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates the problem. nobody can help you by just looking at the data

Comment: Ok il try to add more